# I believe there is a logical math problem with my code, but I cannot put my finger where is it and why

Tags: java, for-loop, math

This my code and when i try to test the difference for input of 100 i get 24501794 instead of 25164150, here is my code:

```
class DifferenceOfSquaresCalculator {

    

    int computeSquareOfSumTo(int input) {
        int sumOfNatural = 0;
        int sumOfNaturalSquared = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < input; i++){
            sumOfNatural+=i;
        }
        sumOfNaturalSquared = (int) Math.pow(sumOfNatural,2);
        return sumOfNaturalSquared;
    }

    int computeSumOfSquaresTo(int input) {
        int sumOfSquaredNaturals = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < input; i++){
            i = (int) Math.pow(i, 2);
            sumOfSquaredNaturals+=i;
        }
        return sumOfSquaredNaturals;
    }

    int computeDifferenceOfSquares(int input) {
        int difference = computeSquareOfSumTo(input) - computeSumOfSquaresTo(input);

        return difference;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1 to 100, i see my problem, thank you

Comment: there is more then 1 problem, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with this code.

At first, you count the series excluding the last number:

`for (int i = 1; i < input; i++)`
should be
`for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)`

At second, in your `computeSumOfSquaresTo` you are changing the loop variable `i` inside the loop.
Try this instead:

```
int computeSumOfSquaresTo(int input) {
    int sumOfSquaredNaturals = 0;            
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {       
        sumOfSquaredNaturals += i * i;       
    }                                        
    return sumOfSquaredNaturals;             
}
```

You can also use a simpler approach using StreamAPI:

```
int computeSquareOfSum(int input) {
    int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, input).sum();
    return sum * sum;
}

int computeSumOfSquares(int input) {
   return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, input).map(i -> i*i).sum();
}
```

or, with same result, you may use just one function:

```
int computeDifferenceOfSquares(int input) {
    int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, input).sum();
    int sumOfSquares = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, input).map(i -> i * i).sum();
    return sum * sum - sumOfSquares;
}
```